# android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.facebook.flatbuffers.helpers.FlatBufferModelHelper$LazyHolder

Tags: android, android-facebook, parcel, badparcelableexception

I'm seeing this crash in Crashlytics for an app that's currently in production:

```
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.facebook.flatbuffers.helpers.FlatBufferModelHelper$LazyHolder
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
   at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:5632)
   ...
```

I'm really unsure of what could be causing this issue. I can't even find a `FlatBufferModelHelper` class in the [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

Unfortunately, I don't really have any more information than this. This crash does seem to affect all devices of all API levels.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: did you managed to get solve it?

Comment: @Karthi sorry, I haven't yet found a solution 

Comment: @charles-madere which version do you user? I am getting the same error in 4.19.0

Comment: @engincancan we're on `4.17.0`, I haven't tried any newer version yet. But I also haven't taken the time to look into this issue again for a while either.

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Comment: Sorry @ashutiwari4, I haven't been on this project in a long time and haven't looked into the issue since. 